# python getter and setter methods for list and += operator

Tags: python, getter-setter

I am building a class which has a dictionary that contains several lists along with other variables. I would like for people using the class to be able to add items to the lists, but I want to go through a setter method so that I can ensure that the values they add to the list are valid. The getter method serves more as a convenience for the user so that it wont be necessary to type variable.dictionary['value']['subvalue']['third nested thing'] just to get at a value.

I have something that works, but the setter method is called when you use the equals operator. I was wondering if it is possible to call the setter method when += is called since the user will be adding to a list. That just seems more natural.

Here is some pseudocode of what I've done so far

```
def addItemtoList(self,inValue):
    if inValue in listOfAcceptableValues:
        self.really['long']['nested']['dictionaries']['array'] = list( set( self.really['long']['nested']['dictionaries']['array'] + [inValue] ) )

def getDeeplyNestedList(self):
    return self.really['long']['nested']['dictionaries']['array']

thatList = property(getDeeplyNestedList, addItemtoList)
```

Comment: To me it looks like everything will be much easier and readable if you created several simple objects and use composition.

Comment: That's tricky because `a += b` *seems* like it should have the same behavior as `a = a + b`, but it actually doesn't; it modifies the list in place, like `a.extend(b)`. I don't know if you can get around that without subclassing `list`.

Comment: By the way, you can have dictionaries all the way down without having to write your own class using `defaultdict`: `from collections import defaultdict` `def make_infinite_dict():` `return defaultdict(make_infinite_dict)` `my_infinite_dict = make_infinite_dict()`

Comment: Juan: I'm not quite sure how to do what you've described. Would you be willing to mock up some pseudocode to show me what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

There's not much point creating a temporary set just to use it for a one off membership test. Might as well just to a linear search of the `list`

```
def addItemtoList(self,inValue):
    L = self.really['long']['nested']['dictionaries']['array']
    if inValue in listOfAcceptableValues and inValue not in L:
        L.append(inValue)
```

When someone tries to extend the list using

```
foo.thatList += ['Some', 'items']
```

the `list.extend` method is called on the list, so the `addItemtoList` isn't involved at all. To achieve what you want, you'll need to have `thatList` return a wrapped version of the list. Either composition or subclassing will work